# How to get all Attached Properties that are set to a DependencyObject in WinRT?

Tags: .net, reflection, windows-runtime, attached-properties

What I want is to retrieve all the attached properties that are set to an instance of a Depedency Object.

For instance. If I have a `<Button x:Name="myButton" Grid.Row="2">` later in the code, I want to be able to retrieve a list of the Attached Properties that has been set to the instance. Something like

```
List<DependencyProperty> attachedProperties = GetAttachedProperties(myButton);
```

Should return a List with the Grid.RowProperty Attached Property, since that it has been explicitly set to the instance of myButton.

Comment: Did you mean via reflection or actual Attached properties (dependency properties)?

Comment: I mean Attached properties. They are Dependency Properties that are registered by one type, but can belong to other types. Like Canvas.Left. How do you get them if they aren't normally declared in one type? A Button, for instance, can inherit a Grid.Row.

Comment: So, given the `Grid`, find all properties that are attachable? You mentioned the button, but a button could accept any attached property.

Comment: I see the point. Maybe I have to rethink the problem. It's true that any DependencyObject can accept any attached property, so it isn't even possible to retrieve all properties attached to one instance of a DependencyObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way [I am doing it](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging/Common/DependencyPropertyCache.cs) in my visual tree debugger tool is I scan the known assemblies in the package for all types and check for static properties of type `DependencyProperty`, then use a few heuristics to determine whether the dependency properties are attached - I check if there is a regular CLR property name-mapped to the dependency property (if there isn't - it usually indicates an attached property). Otherwise - if there is a Get method - it usually indicates an attached property. Once you have a list of all properties - you can call `ReadLocalValue` on the `DependencyObject` and if you get `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` as a result - the property is not set on the object.

If anyone has a better method for doing it - I would really like to hear it since it would be great if I can simplify my code.

Oh and by the way - that's not a code I would ship in a store app. I use it for diagnostics/debugging only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that you just cannot query for all properties attached to a Dependency Object. Attached Properties are actually no part of the instance itself, but by the type that registers it.

For my problem, I initially wanted to retrieve all the attached properties set to a Dependency Object, but later discovered that what I really needed is to be able to get a Attached Property from a string like "Canvas.Left" and a Dependency Object (target). I just have to get the information from the string, query the declared properties from Canvas and find LeftProperty. Then, I can get or set its value using Target.GetValue(dp).